# Is the isomorphism type of $TM$ as a topological vector bundle determined by the homeomorphism type of $M$?

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology, tangent-bundle

Let $M, N$ be smooth manifolds with the same underlying topological manifold $X$. Are $TM$ and $TN$ isomorphic, regarded as topological vector bundles over $X$?

Comment: In the related questions: [no](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469992/tangent-bundles-of-exotic-manifolds?rq=1)

Comment: @ConnorMalin Thanks.

Comment: @EricWofsey And thanks to you too.